# How to write OOP consistent code with duck typing?

Tags: python, oop, duck-typing

I'm having trouble in deciding on the placement of method in a python program, where it seems like the duck-typing approach I'm used to rely on is at odds with my OOP instincts.

To illustrate, suppose we have three classes: Hero, Sword and Apple. A hero can equip a sword and a hero can eat an apple.

If I were to follow my OOP gut, I think the code would look like this:

**duckless.py**

```
class Hero:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weapon = None
        self.inTummy = None

    def equip(self, weapon):
        weapon.define()
        print("I shall equip it.")
        self.weapon = weapon

    def eat(self, food):
        food.define()
        print("I shall consume it.")
        self.inTummy = food

class Sword:
    def define(self):
        print("'tis a shiny sword")

class Apple:
    def define(self):
        print("'tis a plump apple")

hero = Hero()
swd = Sword()
apl = Apple()

hero.equip(swd)
hero.eat(apl)
```

Which feels very intuitive and readable.

If I were to duck-type, however, I feel like the code would look something like this:

**duckfull.py**

```
class Hero:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weapon = None
        self.inTummy = None

    def onEquip(self):
        print("I shall equip it.")

    def onEat(self):
        print("I shall eat it.")

class Sword:
    def define(self):
        print("'tis a shiny sword")

    def equip(self, hero):
        self.define()
        hero.onEquip()
        hero.weapon = self


class Apple:
    def define(self):
        print("'tis a plump apple")

    def eat(self, hero):
        self.define()
        hero.onEat()
        hero.inTummy = self

hero = Hero()
swd = Sword()
apl = Apple()

swd.equip(hero)
apl.eat(hero)
```

The duck-typed code has the clear advantage that I can perform a **try-except** at any time to determine whether I'm performing a "legal" action:

```
try:
    apl.equip()
except AttributeError:
    print("I can't equip that!")
```

Which feels very pythonic, while the alternative would require me to perform dreaded *type checks*.

However, from an OOP standpoint, it feels weird to be that a **sword** is responsible for equipping itself, and that it receives a **hero** as a parameter. The act of equipping seems like an action performed by the **hero**, and as such, I feel the method should belong in the **Hero** class. The whole syntax of

```
def eat(self, hero):
    self.define()
    hero.onEat()
    hero.inTummy = self
```

Feels very alien.

Is either approach more pythonic? Is either more OOP consistent? Should I be looking at a different solution altogether?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this belongs in our code-review page, not StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to the site. Is there a way I could move this question there, or should I delete it and re-ask it in the proper page?

Comment: Could you define an `Item` superclass, and have `Hero` implement an `activate()` method, that calls the overriden `Item`'s `activate()` function? That way you can simply call hero.activate(item) and depending on your subclass of `Item`, it will call `eat()` or `equip()` accordingly.

Comment: I think the duck-typed is alright, and the two are not too far away in reality. The truth lies in the middle sometimes. Try to expand and proceed with the methods in both cases.

Comment: I think this question is fine for StackOverflow.  It's not code-review because this code isn't actually doing anything.  It's a good question about programming practice, with a toy example.

Comment: @MeetTitan I could, but I don't feel that fully solves my issue, since eat() and equip() aren't necessarily equivalent, or mutually exclusive. Suppose I have a Jerky Armor item, that's able to call both eat() and equip(). How would Hero.active() resolve the ambiguity?

Comment: @Zayora, if your class implements both, then have a default action, or ask the user for more fine grained input. Maybe a drop down selecting either equip or eat, since you'll have to ask the user anyways, considering the item can be consumed in multiple ways.

Comment: @MeetTitan maybe, but I'm afraid that might go against the principle of duck-typing I'm trying to abide to. I wanted to be able to simply try to equip or eat an item at will, and have the repercussions be dealt with by a well placed try-except block. I think I'm going with BrenBarn's answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no clear-cut answer; it depends on what your classes do.  It is not so horrible to check `isinstance(weapon, Weapon)` in your `Hero.equip` to check if the item is a weapon.  Also, if you're going to involve both objects as in your second example, you can move more of the handling into the Hero:

```
class Hero:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weapon = None
        self.inTummy = None

    def equip(self, weapon):
        print("I shall equip it.")
        self.weapon = weapon

class Sword:
    def equip(self, hero):
        hero.equip(self)
```

This may seem a bit strange, but it is not necessarily a bad thing to have a method on one class that just delegates to a related method on another class (as, here, calling `sword.equip` just calls `hero.equip`).  You could also do it the other way around, and have `Hero.equip` call `weapon.equip()` or `weapon.ready()` or whatever, which will fail if the item isn't a weapon and so doesn't have such an attribute.

The other thing is that you can still have duck-typing behavior in your first example, it's just that the error won't be raised until a later stage when you try to do something else with the weapon.  Something like:

```
hero.equip(apple)  # no error
hero.weapon.calculateDamage() # AttributeError: Apple object has no attribute `damage`
```

This may not be considered ideal, because you don't know you equipped an invalid weapon until later.  But that's how duck-typing works: you don't know if you did something wrong until you actually attempt an action that triggers that wrongness.

If all you're going to do with an object is throw it, a bowling ball will work as well as a duck.  It's only when you try to make it swim or fly or whatever that you'll notice the bowling ball is not a duck.  Likewise, if all you're going to do to equip a "weapon" is strap it to your belt or hold it in your hand, you can do that with an apple as well as with a sword; you won't notice anything amiss until you try to actually wield the apple in battle.

Comment: I understand I could have it return an error once I tried to call the method of a weapon from an apple, but to me it seems unnatural that the apple ever got equipped at all. Your other approach, on the other hand, seems much more aligned with what I'm going for. In this case, where do you suppose the attributing of the sword object to the hero's "weapon" attribute would take place? Inside Hero.equip()? Thanks for the help!

Comment: _If all you're going to do with an object is throw it, a bowling ball will work as well as a duck._ No animals were harmed in the making of this answer?

Comment: @zayora: Oops, yes, I meant for that to go in the hero's `equip`, but I see I didn't write that correctly.  I've edited my code example.